# Buscar resultados a 3 tabela com a data dos últimos 5 dias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou a tentar fazer é ir buscar o nomde de utilizadores que não tem nenhum registo na `tbl_votos` e nenhum recurso na `tbl_recursos` nos últimos **5 dias**. Estou a usar php e mysql.

Comment: o "id" de cada tabela é a chave primária

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma seria utilizando um not exists, da seguinte forma:

```
select *
  from tbl_utilizadores u
 where not exists (select 1 from tbl_votos v where v.id_user = u.id and v.data > (NOW() - interval 5 day) )
   and not exists (select 1 from tbl_recursos r where r.id_user = u.id  and r.data > (NOW() - interval 5 day))
```

Só não sei se a forma de pegar a data está correta.

Para colocar a data do ultimo voto e recurso, basta colocar no select:

```
select u.*, (select MAX(v1.data) from tbl_votos v1.id_user = u.id) as "Data Voto", (select MAX(r1.data) from tbl_recursos r1 where r1.id_user = u.id) as "Data Recurso"
```

do from em diante fica igual.

Comment: é possível fazer essa consulta mas apresentar as datas das tabelas também?

Comment: Vc quer dizer, apresentar as datas dos ultimos votos e recursos, se houver?

Comment: select u.*, (select MAX(v1.data) from tbl_votos v1.id_user = u.id) as "Data Voto", (select MAX(r1.data) from tbl_recursos r1 where r1.id_user = u.id) as "Data Recurso"

Comment: O que eu quero é mostrar os utilizadores que não tem recursos e votos nos últimos 5 dias (isto faz a sua query),agora queria também mostrar a data da ultima vez que esse utilizador fez um recurso e votou se possível.

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa, fazendo `LEFT JOIN` e verificando quais retornaram nulo:

```
SELECT
    u.nome
FROM
    tbl_utilizadores AS u
    LEFT JOIN tbl_recursos AS r
        ON r.id_user = u.id AND r.data > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_votos AS v
        ON v.id_user = u.id AND v.data > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
WHERE
    r.id IS NULL
    AND v.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nome, COUNT(tb2.id) recursos, COUNT(tb3.id) votos
FROM tbl_utilizadores tb
LEFT JOIN tbl_recursos tb2 ON tb.id = tb2.id_user AND tb2.data > (NOW() - interval 5 day)
LEFT JOIN tbl_votos tb3 ON tb.id = tb3.id_user AND tb3.data > (NOW() - interval 5 day)
GROUP BY tb.id
HAVING recursos = 0 AND votos = 0
```

Acredito que essa seria a melhor forma.

Comment: a sua query não retorna nenhum valor, e tenho utilizadores nesta condição

Comment: Fiz uma edição na query adicionando um group by por id

Comment: penso que a sua query tem um resso, está a igualar o tb.id = tb4.id_user. Não devia ser tb.id_user= tb4.id_user? obrigado

Comment: O id_user num corresponde ao id da tabela tbl_utilizadores não?

Comment: não, penso que tem bem. eu é que fiz confusão. obrigado

Comment: Se o seu banco estiver todo indexados e com as devidas chaves extrangeiras a resposta do Lucas será mais rápida e menos custosa para o banco, caso contrário a do Sertage ta melhor